# Как выбрать количество записей из другой таблицы по дате в одном запросе?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql9.6

Пытаюсь выбрать сгруппированные данные из одной таблицы и дополнить количеством записей из другой.

Структура таблиц такая:

```
t1:
  id
  created_at (timestamp)
  price (double)

t2:
  id
  created_at (timestamp)
  type (enum(1,2))
```

Я пытаюсь сделать вот такой запрос:

```
select
    date(t1.created_at) as date,
    t1.price,
    (select count(*) from t2 t21 where date(t1.created_at) = date(t21.created_at) and type = 1) as cnt1,
    (select count(*) from t2 t22 where date(t1.created_at) = date(t22.created_at) and type = 2) as cnt2
from t1
group by date, t1.price
```

Получаю ошибку `subquery uses ungrouped column "t1.created_at" from outer query`

Как же мне выбрать count из другой таблице по дате?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT date(t1.created_at) as date,
       t1.price,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN 1 END) count1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = 2 THEN 1 END) count2
FROM t1
LEFT /* или INNER */ JOIN t2 ON date(t1.created_at) = date(t2.created_at)
group by date(t1.created_at), t1.price
```

**UPDATE:** предыдущий запрос неверен.

```
SELECT t11.date, 
       t11.price,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN t2.type = 1 THEN 1 END)) count1,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN t2.type = 2 THEN 1 END)) count2
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT date(t1.created_at) as date,
                       t1.price as price
       FROM t1
     ) t11
LEFT /* или INNER */ JOIN t2 ON t11.date = date(t2.created_at)
group by t11.date, t11.price
```

Comment: Добавил else 0, избавился от null.

Comment: Ну это уже по вкусу...

Comment: Считает неверно, к сожалению

Comment: У меня всего 6 записей в таблице t2, а сумма из всей выборки 9

Comment: Тип отклонения? потому как единственная видимая навскидку точка проблемы - некорректность условия связывания `date(t1.created_at) = date(t2.created_at)`. *сумма из всей выборки 9* Эммм... а в группу по `date(t1.created_at), t1.price` что, попадает несколько записей из таблицы t1???

Comment: Я добавил в t2 3 записи на одну дату. Сумму count1 и count2 получил 6.

Comment: Похоже, я понял, в чем дело. В t1 2 записи на эту дату, сначала считается количество, а потом происходит группировка. Получается, работает правильно, спасибо. Правда, я не понимаю, что нужно сделать, что бы не перемножалось. В оригинале я считаю count из одной таблицы и дополняю count-ами из других

Comment: *Я добавил в t2 3 записи на одну дату.* Да ещё и с одинаковой ценой, что ли? *я не понимаю, что нужно сделать, что бы не перемножалось.* А вот тут ответ зависит от бизнес-логики. Возможно, их надо сгруппировать в одну запись (тогда вместо таблицы t1 будет подзапрос из неё с группировкой по `date(t1.created_at), t1.price`), иначе ... зависит от сути бизнес-процесса и может быть всякоразно.